# Issue calculating an equation in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, math

I am trying to solve this formula in my program:

`=10^(-1*(107.8871+0.03252849*297-5151.79/297-38.92561*log(297)+563713.9/297^2))`

And the final correct answer I should get is `4.58E-11` unfortunately that is not what I am getting, this is how I am programming this:

```
int X19 = pow(10, (-1*(107.8871+0.03252849*297-5151.79/297-38.92561* log(297)+563713.9/pow(297, 2))));
```

But the answer that I get when I run the program is : `-2147483648`

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT** = After changing the obvious error on my behalf to change the type of to a `double` instead of an `int`, my new answer is now = `10948824009217039033385554100376102490822180576034479094375076006115616972742335036083272081670698970658879817383936.000000` which is still not my answer, any other

Comment: Exactly how is a floating point `4.58E-11` **EVER** going to fit into an `int` without being corrupted?

Comment: You are right, I have updated the question @MarcB

Comment: @vzm Then explain what is your expected result, and the equivalent formula that you're trying to compute.

Comment: @RamyAlZuhouri I dont understand what you need to me to explain? Its all written in the question, the formula that can be easily solved in a calculator in on line no.2 and the expected result is on line no.3 of my question

Comment: Well I saw the question before the edit and I didn't reload the page.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `log` routine is a natural logarithm, with base *e*, but you want `log10`, with base 10.

Comment: I have changed this, but new answer equals `0.000000` not the `4.58E-11` I would get in a calculator

Comment: @vzm: Print with a format specification, such as `%g`, that will show small numbers. The default fixed-precision format shows 4.58e-11 as zero.

Comment: Thank you very much for great, to the point/ non rude answer! 1 up & answer awarded!

Comment: Is there a way to print `4.58e-11` instead of the current also right answer of `4.58062e-11` ?

Comment: Oh, I forgot that calculators usually use `ln()` for natural log and `log()` for the base-10 logarithm. That would certainly explain vzm's issue.

Comment: @vzm The `%.3g` format specifier does the trick. That will give you (up to) 3 significant figures, i.e. `4.58`(e-11).

Comment: @JAB worked perfectly, thanks for the great effort I have also 1^ your good answer.

Answer (score 3):

`int`s can only be whole numbers. `4.58E-11` is `0.0000000000458`, so you should be using a floating- or fixed-point decimal data type. If you're okay with the possibility of rounding errors (which you might get with your floating-point literals anyway), then you can simply use the `double` data type instead of `int`.

This doesn't take into account the possibility of overflows or other issues with data storage limitations, however. Note that when the format is changed to double, the result is still not what you want: http://ideone.com/PMoyJA (And you've noted that, I see.) This doesn't seem to be an issue with data types, however, but with your equation; I'm pretty sure your order of operations is incorrect, or your equation is incorrect in some other way. Using the following assignments:

```
double x8 = 0.03252849 * 297; // 9.660962
double x9 = 107.8871 + x8; // 117.548062
double x10 = 5151.79 / 297; // 17.346094
double x11 = x9 - x10; // 100.201967
double x12 = log(297); // 5.693732
double x13 = 38.92561 * x12; // 221.631997
double x14 = x11 - x13; // -121.430029
double x15 = pow(297, 2); // 88209.000000
double x16 = 563713.9 / x15; // 6.390662
double x17 = -(x14 + x16); // 115.039367
double x18 = pow(10, x17); // 10948824009217039033385554100376102490822180576034479094375076006115616972742335036083272081670698970658879817383936.000000
```

1. For `x18` to be `4.58E-11`, `x17` must be equal to `-23.80673702480841`, not `115.039367`.
2. As `x17 = -(x14 + x16)`, that means `x14 == -x17 - x16 == 23.80673702480841-563713.9/pow(297, 2) == 17.4160750742138`, not `-121.430029`.
3. As `x14 = x11 -x13 == x11 - 38.92561*log(297)`, that means `x11 == 17.4160750742138 + 38.92561*log(297) == 239.04807175371357`, not `100.201967`.
4. `x11 = x9 - x10` --> `x9 == x11 + 5151.79 / 297 == 239.04807175371357 + 5151.79 / 297 == 256.3941660298078`, not `117.548062`
5. `x9 = 107.8871 + x8` --> `x8 == x9 - 107.8871 == 256.3941660298078 - 107.8871 == 148.50706602980782`, not `9.660962`.

Comment: Once I read it, I knew this one was obvious mistake, and while I appreciate you pointing that out to me, it still does not give me the answer that I am looking for out of the equation, I have updated the question to reflect the change and new answer @JAB